# What should I do with date column in dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

Actually I'm working on the Australia weather dataset to predict whether it will rain tomorrow or not?
I'm new to machine learning and I don't know what to do with the date column in my dataset because I know machines only take numerical values.

So plz tell me what I should do with this date how should I deal with it[image]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract year, month and day number of date as categorical variable. It can be significant what month, year or whether it is the beginning or the end of the month.

If you tell me what kind of language you are using I can help you with code :)

Comment: I'm using Python.

Comment: You mean that I create 3 separate columns of the day, month and year.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can do this by:

import pandas as pd

df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).year
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).month
df['day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).day

Comment: Plz also tell me how to deal with windgustdr column to windspeed3pm,  should i used label encoding and one hot coder, but this also create to many columns and there are already too many columns

Answer (score 0):

Hey Navin Bondade,
When you are using onehotencoding and supposedly, the column contains too many values, then automatically too many columns pile up in your dataset. So, you have to pick 10 or 15 most frequent values in that particular feature and try to encode them and leave the rest out. I haven't used it personally, but I did see a team win the KDD Orange Cup with this technique.
Happy Learning !!